# Get current user in custom Symfony ErrorController

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I implemented a custom error controller for Symfony 5 to customize the error page, which works fine.
Sadly at the point this error controller is executed, the security system of symfony isn't initialized.
Is there a way to manually trigger the security system to login the current user?
I use the new Authenticator based security system with a custom authenticator which reads an already existing session.

I tried to use my authenticator directly to get the user:

```php
class ErrorController extends \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ErrorController {

  public function __construct(
    ...
    private AbstractAuthenticator $authenticator,
    private RequestStack $requestStack,
    ...
  ) {
    parent::__construct($kernel, $controller, $errorRenderer);
  }

  public function __invoke(\Throwable $exception): Response {
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $user = $this->authenticator->supports($request)
      ? $this->authenticator->authenticate($request)->getUser()
      : null;

    return parent::__invoke($exception); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
  }


}
```

This works, but the next step would be to inject the user into the symfony security system which is not a good idea since I use (abuse) the framework in a way it isn't intended and it also bypasses the authenticators set in the config.

So, is there a way to run the security system of symfony at this point in a way it is intended to run?

Comment: What's in the session data? Usually the user id is stored in the session data. You could use that to fetch the user from storage.

Comment: What do you desire to do with the logged in user? Is this where you are trying to do something with the display that requires the logged in user which isn't initialized? Trying to see the full scope of what you want to do

Comment: The user object has the language of the current user, which I need for displaying the error message in the correct translation.

Comment: Hmmm.  In production apps should only be displaying very generic error messages if that.  But yes, if you really want to pull the user id out of the session and do a direct query you could I suppose.  Or store the language as part of the user's serialized data.